# Extract entire string containing xml tags from request form in Java

Tags: java, xml, string, jaxb, marshalling

I have created a SOAP web service in Spring Boot and the request object has a field of string type called block which contains an xml content. When I try to extract the value of block field (by using getter method), it returns empty string. Is there a way to extract its value as a plain string?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
<message>
                <block>
                    <batch>
                        <msg_subtype>150</msg_subtype>
                        <body>:20:O18385649
                        </body>
                        <sign>MIICTgYJKoZIhvcNAQcCo</sign>
                    </batch>
                </block>
                <msgCopySrvId/>
                <msgCopySrvInfo/>
                <msgDelNotifRq>N</msgDelNotifRq>
                <msgFinValidation/>
                <msgAmount>55982,55</msgAmount>
</message>
```

I need to return the value of block tag from the request object as a string  :

```
"<batch>
                        <msg_subtype>150</msg_subtype>
                        <body>:20:O18385649
                        </body>
                        <sign>MIICTgYJKoZIhvcNAQcCo</sign>
</batch>"
```

Here is my Java code:

```
public JAXBElement<SendT> createRequestXml(JAXBElement<SendT> sendT) {

        var message = sendT.getValue().getMessage();
        
        if (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(message.getBlock)) {
            message.setBlock(message.getBlock().replace("/", "S"));
        }
        sendT.getValue().setMessage(message);

        return sendT;
    }
```

SendT class is generated from xsd:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "send_t", propOrder = {
    "message"
})
public class SendT {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Params message;
// getter and setter

}
```

Params class:

```
public class Params {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String block;
    protected String msgCopySrvId;
    protected String msgCopySrvInfo;
    protected String msgDelNotifRq;
    protected String msgFinValidation;
    protected String msgAmount;
    //getter and setters
}
```

Comment: Please,take some time to read [how to provide a minimum, reproducible example](/help/mcve)

Comment: Added more details

Comment: There's no java code there, what have you tried so far? It could be done using XPath.

Comment: I have added my Java code. The problem is that createRequestXml() method returns block field empty if I include a string with xml content as in example above.

Comment: `Params` must be a bean with proper getters/setters.

Comment: There are getters/setters in the Params class. The problem is that when I manually provide  message.setBlock("<batch>
                        <msg_subtype>150</msg_subtype>
                        <body>:20:O18385649
                        </body>
                        <sign>MIICTgYJKoZIhvcNAQcCo</sign>
                    </batch>").replace("/", "S");  it works fine. But when I write  message.setBlock(message.getBlock().replace("/", "S")); with the request form above I get empty block field

Comment: `!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(message.getBlock())` missing parenthesis? Also, `message.setBlock(message.getBlock())` makes not much sense. How is block supposed to be set then.

Comment: It's actually (!ObjectUtils.isEmpty(message.getBlock)). The code compliles fine. The issue is that I get an empty block field when it is sent in the form of xml content

Comment: `block`is an String. Which object type is `message.getBlock` without parenthesis

Comment: Solved the issue by adding new Java classes for both block and batch elements.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by adding new Java classes for block and batch elements.